# How Do I Get Data from OLE DB Query

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Allow me to prove how new I am to Visual Basic and OLE DB coding. My intention is to simply retrieve the value of one field from a query that I'm running. The code below works but it seems ugly to me.I am using a DataAdapter and DataSet to fill a DataGridView, because that's the only way to get the information. The SQL retrieves one row so I know that the field I want will always be in Row 0, Cell 0 and I can move that into my variable strArchID. I'm guessing there might be a better way to do this (DataReader) but I can't figure out how to use it. I'd appreciate any suggestions including sample code.

```
    Try
        Dim mySQLArchID = "SELECT ArchID, ArchUserName, ArchUserDomain, ArchDate, ArchRoot FROM Archives WHERE " &
        "ArchUserName = @UserName AND " &
        "ArchUserDomain = @UserDomain AND " &
        "ArchDate = @MyArchDate AND " &
        "ArchRoot = @MyArchRoot"
        Using myConn As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
            Using myGetID As New OleDbCommand(mySQLArchID, myConn)
                Dim NameParm = New OleDbParameter("UserName", OleDbType.VarChar)
                Dim DomainParm = New OleDbParameter("UserDomain", OleDbType.VarChar)
                Dim DateParm = New OleDbParameter("MyArchDate", OleDbType.Date)
                Dim RootParm = New OleDbParameter("MyArchRoot", OleDbType.VarChar)
                Dim myAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
                NameParm.Value = strArchUser
                DomainParm.Value = strArchDomain
                DateParm.Value = dteArchDate
                RootParm.Value = strArchRoot
                myGetID.Parameters.Add(NameParm)
                myGetID.Parameters.Add(DomainParm)
                myGetID.Parameters.Add(DateParm)
                myGetID.Parameters.Add(RootParm)
                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myGetID
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                ds.Clear()
                myAdapter.Fill(ds, "Archives")
                dgvData.DataSource = ds
                dgvData.DataMember = "Archives"
                strArchID = dgvData.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Get Arch ID did not work")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a single value from a database then you create a command object and call `ExecuteScalar`. Even the parts of your code that you would keep can be simplified a lot.

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT ArchID
           FROM Archives
           WHERE ArchUserName = @ArchUserName
           AND ArchUserDomain = @ArchUserDomain
           AND ArchDate = @ArchDate
           AND ArchRoot = @ArchRoot"

Using connection As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString),
      command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
    With command.Parameters
        .Add("@ArchUserName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strArchUser
        .Add("@ArchUserDomain", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strArchDomain
        .Add("@ArchDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = dteArchDate
        .Add("@ArchRoot", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strArchRoot
    End With

    connection.Open()
    strArchID = CStr(command.ExecuteScalar())
End Using
```

1. Recent VB versions have supported multiline `String` literals and they help make SQL code far more readable. Even before that though, you could still use an XML literal.
2. Don't include columns in your query that you don't actually need. Use the column name for corresponding parameters unless you have a specific reason for not doing so.
3. You don't need to nest `Using` blocks unless you need to interleave code between them. A single `Using` statement can create as many objects as you like.
4. Don't use the same complex expression multiple times. Either use a `With` block or assign the expression to a variable and then use the multiple times.
5. Don't use multistep code to create and add parameters unless the steps are in different places. Otherwise, call `Add` and it will return the new parameter object that you can then set the `Value` property of. Also specify the size for variable-size data types. I have used 50 as an example but you should use your own size from the database.
6. `ExecuteScalar` can be used to execute any query but will only return the first column of the first row of the result set. If there are no rows, `DBNull.Value` is returned. The value is returned as an `Object` reference, so you will need to cast it as the actual type of the data. That cast will not be valid if the result is NULL, so be aware of whether you need to allow for that.

For more ADO.NET examples, see [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872).

Comment: With OleDb (Access) the order that the parameters are added to the parameters collection (with the `.Add` method) must match the order that they appear in the sql query.

Comment: Regarding the points above, I hope you don't mind some follow-up questions.

Comment: Regarding the points above, I hope you don't mind some follow-up questions. First of all, thank you for the code it worked perfectly and is much more efficient than mine.First question - In your Dim sql statement, I thought you had to specify a data type on all Dim statements. Does it default to string? Second, a comment/question - The reason I included the extra fields in my Select statement is that I was getting an SQL error if I included a field in my WHERE clause but wasn't selecting it. This however works for you. I don't understand., Lastly, Can you only use ExecuteScalar whn get 1 field

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin, yes `String` default.

Comment: @evry1falls No, the default is not String. If there is an assignment to the variable and Option Infer in project properties is set to On, the compiler will infer the datatype. You can hold your cursor over the variable to see what the compiler has decided. If there is a default, it would be object but I don't think the vb compiler will allow it.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin A variable inside a method can skip the datatype if an assignment is made in the same line and Option Infer is set to On in the project properties. The compiler is able to infer the datatype from what is assigned. Class level variables always require a datatype.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin You can use `.ExecuteScalar` with any Select but it will only return the first column of the first row of your result set.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin I suspect that your error regarding fields in the Where clause but not in the Select portion of the query was really due to something else. This should not cause a problem.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin, with `Option Strict Off` (the default) the compiler will assume type `Object` for any variable for which it cannot determine a different data type. You should pretty much always have `Option Strict On`. In that case, the compiler must be able to determine a specific data type for every variable. With `Option Infer On` (the default) you can initialise a local variable where you declare it and the compiler will infer the data type of the variable from the initialising expression if no type is specified. With `Option Infer Off` you must specify a data type explicitly.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin, *"Can you only use ExecuteScalar whn get 1 field"*. That is already addressed in point 6 of the answer.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin, *"I suspect that your error regarding fields in the Where clause but not in the Select portion of the query was really due to something else"*. I'd have to agree with @Mary here. If you can reproduce the SQL and the error message then we may be able to determine the cause but there is no requirement to include a column in the `SELECT` clause because it's included in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I have a strange problem - at least it seems strange to me. The ArchID field that this code retrieves is an autonum field in Access with format "Arch"0  This works fine. The latest value on the table, when I look at it in MS-Access, is Arch61. My problem is that when I run the code above it retries only the number portion - i.e..61 instead of Arch61. What causes this and is there a way around it? I know I could concatenate the number retrieved with an "Arch" literal but this seems like kind of a dirty fix.

Comment: It's important to understand the difference between an Access database and the Access application. For an `AutoNumber` field, the database only contains the number. All the format stuff, regardless of data type, is something that the Access application adds in the UI layer when it displays the data. Access is literally concatenating "Arch" to that number for display purposes so your "dirty fix" is literally what's already happening in Access.

Comment: Thank you. That's pretty much what I suspected when I started to see this problem.